# Shader rendering upside down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hlsl

I'm trying to implement this glow/highlight shader into my project.

http://xroft666.blogspot.com.au/

But for some reason, the render is upside down and not lining up with the mesh.

I have no experience with shaders. here is a screenshot:

[image]

I'm sort of guessing that the return value of "o" is at fault.

```
        struct v2f {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float4 projPos : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        v2f vert( float4 v : POSITION ) {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v );
            o.projPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);   


            return o;
        }
```

Is it possible to invert a specific axis of "o"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know very little about shaders, but I downloaded the implementation example project from the blog and checked the shader. I noticed there are a few `// invert for OPENGL` sections. This might be relevant for you?

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, you were spot on,

Comment: I commented out invert for opengl at line 36 to 38 and did the trick

Comment: Nice! Your game looks awesome btw!